# Codepipeline:Than access token might be invalid or has been revoked.insufficient permission

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github

I am beginner for this AWS/GitHub things.please guide me how to resolve this issue.Please let me know if you want any other details.

Thanks in advance!!

Code pipeline is not working after code merge from dev to uat environment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.